# Browser control NavigateToString display HTML code instead of rendering page

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am developing a browser app using Windows Phone 8 browser control.

The app download an external webpage using WebClient into a string in the background. Then the browser navigate to the content using

`webBrowser.NavigateToString(str);`

However, instead of rendering the page, the browser shows the HTML code. I thought since no changes were made to the string, `NavigateToString` should handle it seamlessly. Or perhaps I am missing something.

So how do I display the HTML page instead of its code?

**EDIT**

Here's some of my code

```
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));



    private  void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         PageString = e.Result;
    }

    ...

     webBrowser.NavigateToString(PageString);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with Windows Phone 8.

[Here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/webbrowser-navigatetostring-broken-in-windows-phone-8-and-also-affects-windows-phone-7-apps-solution-included) you have a workaround.

Comment: Thank you ! (btw you should edit your post to add the solution here !)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `DownloadStringAsync`, it also downloads the `DOCTYPE` declaration. You can remove this and start your code with the `<html>` block as `NavigateToString` doesn't seem to like the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` declaration.

```
webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //remove "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
    PageString = e.Result.Replace("<!DOCTYPE HTML>","").Trim();        
}

webBrowser.NavigateToString(PageString);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to remove the Doctype, as it will break some of your CSS. It will solve the problem, yes, but that comes at a cost.

Comment: Have you seen this happen in practice? Not saying you're wrong but the `WebBrowser` control may prepend this internally.

Comment: Yes, this happens in an actual app I've built for WP8!

Comment: The issue: My CSS is bound to some data-attributes on the `html` tag. Removing the DOCTYPE seems to automatically ditch the `html` tag too!

Comment: Ah, interesting. It seems you'll have to take the approach of storing it in IsolatedStorage if you're using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [WebBrowser.NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) says:

*If the text parameter is not in valid HTML format, it will be displayed as plain text.*

Can you check if `str` is in valid HTML format?

```
private  void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     PageString = e.Result;
     webBrowser.NavigateToString(PageString); 
}
```

Comment: I tested downloading from several websites such as CNN.com, BBC.com, Google.com. So shouldn't the HTML be valid?

Comment: Honestly, it should be but it need not necessarily be for `NavigateToString` method. You can try saving the `str` to a file and check if it valid. Moreover, `webBrowser.NavigateToString(PageString);` should be part of the `webClient_DownloadStringCompleted` method rather outside it unless you are keeping track of response with Thread synchronization.

Comment: I don't think checking HTML validity will solve it. Even http://validator.w3.org/ does not render. So `NavigateToString` must be expecting something else.

Comment: 1 quick test, can you check if `m.google.com` or `m.cnn.com` are loading?

Comment: Placing `NavigateToString` inside the method didn't fix it. I don't see how this make a different if the string is unchanged when passed though. Alsom `m.google.com` does show the HTML code. `m.cnn.com` redirected to web page indicating that cookies must be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:

```
        wb.Navigate("");
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while ((wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete));
        wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml = "Html";
```

Comment: Windows phone's web browser has no "Document" property?