# how to load html with javascript in wp8 web browser control?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have web browser control in windows phone 8. i want to load html in my web browser control

my html string is

```
string htmlstring=
   " <html>
    <head>
    <title>Kayako chat</title>
    </head>
    <body><!-- BEGIN FUSION TAG CODE - DO NOT EDIT! -->
    <div>
    <div id=\"proactivechatcontainer6bahdzbxzq\">
    </div>
    <table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\">
    <tr><td align=\"center\" id=\"swifttagcontainer6bahdzbxzq\">
    <div style=\"display: inline;\" id=\"swifttagdatacontainer6bahdzbxzq\">
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var swiftscriptelem6bahdzbxzq=document.createElement(\"script\");
    swiftscriptelem6bahdzbxzq.type=\"text/javascript\";
    var swiftrandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); 
    var swiftuniqueid = \"6bahdzbxzq\"; 
    var swifttagurl6bahdzbxzq=\"http://kcs.kayako.com/visitor/index.php?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\";
    setTimeout(\"swiftscriptelem6bahdzbxzq.src=swifttagurl6bahdzbxzq;
    document.getElementById('swifttagcontainer6bahdzbxzq').appendChild(swiftscriptelem6bahdzbxzq);\",1);
    </script><!-- END FUSION TAG CODE - DO NOT EDIT! -->
    </html>";
```

I did this but not working

```
var htmlCode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString);
WebView1.NavigateToString(htmlCode);
```

Comment: You might have an answer for your question [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16515866/332047

Comment: Doesn't html need a doctype? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Document_type_declaration

Comment: @vonLochow:thanks for re[lay...but no i didnt get solution for this link

Comment: @HMR:no this html conteain one image....i just want to load this image in my web browser control.

Comment: can any one know answer?\

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it:

```
webbrowser1.documenttext = "Html"
```

if its not working:

```
        wb.Navigate("");
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while ((wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete));
        wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml = "Html";
```